# Does it make sense to apply the Manhattan metric to an arbitrary graph?

Tags: graph-theory, metric-spaces

I overheard someone talking about using the Manhattan metric against nodes on an arbitrary graph (or even a tree). At the time, I didn't think much of it, but having dwelled upon it, does it even make sense?

Clearly, said graph would need to be mapped on to an appropriate space (i.e., $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$) in a lattice-like fashion. However, wouldn't this preclude the graph from having more than four edges for any particular vertex?

Does it work if you 'latticify' the graph in to $\mathbb{Z}^n$, where $n=\frac{1}{2}\max (\textrm{#edges per vertex})$ -- or something like that -- and likewise extend the metric into $n$-dimensions?

Comment: Wouldn't the Manhatten metric simply mean that the distance between two vertices is the minimal number of edges for a path between them?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, in finding paths between two cities for driving, an algorithm that uses the embedding of the graph in a metric space (the Earth) is the A* algorithm. Books by Norvig and, early, Judea Pearl. Altering the metric in the ambient space somewhat alters the algorithm, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, I suppose it does :) I was thinking too quantitatively; hence trying to force the graph into $\mathbb{Z}^n$... If you submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.